# Find and replace end of line with Dreamweaver

Tags: mysql, text, dreamweaver

I have a list of web address I'm trying to put into an SQL database. 
The beginning of each line was easy, all I had to do was find/replace "http" with the beginning of the SQL command followed by http.

My question is, how do I do a find and replace at the end of every line, even though they all end with something different?

Comment: I really don't understand what you need. Can you explain better and provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking 'use regular expressions' and type in `\r\n` in the find box.  This will allow you replace all of the white space starting from the end of a line to the beginning of the next line.

See this [Understanding Regular Expressions](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html) article from Adobe for more information.